# Why am I getting C# compiler errors when including gRPC proto file definitions into single proto buf file?

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc, grpc-c#

I'm building out a series of ProtoBuf definitions for a .NetCore gRPC application.
I'm using the Orchestrator pattern as I will be creating a series of microservices.

I am running into issues with my proto definitions throwing compiler errors as being "undefined."
The definitions are in several different files (with different C# namespaces).
What follows is a simplified version of my definitions.

Consider the following protobuf files:

**service.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";
option csharp_namespace = "RequestHandlerService";
package test;

service Handler
{
  rpc AddItem1(G_RequestType1) returns (G_RequestResponse) { }
  rpc AddItem2(G_RequestType2) returns (G_RequestResponse) { }
}

message G_RequestType1{
  string originId = 1;
  string request = 2;
}

message G_RequestType2{
  string originId = 1;
  string request = 2;
}

message G_RequestResponse{
  string response = 1;
}
```

**windowsservice.proto:**

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
option csharp_namespace = "Windows.RequestHandler.Service";
package windows.requesthandler.service;

service WindowsHandler
{
    rpc Action1(G_Action1Request) returns (G_Action1Response) { }
    rpc Action2(G_Action2Request) returns (G_Action2Reponse) { }
}

message G_Action1Request{
    string transactionId = 1;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp DateTimeStamp = 2;
    string filePath = 3;
}

message G_Action2Request{
    string transactionId = 1;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp DateTimeStamp = 2;
    string textToInsert = 3;
}

message G_Action1Response {
    google.protobuf.Timestamp DateTimeStamp = 1;
    string fileSecurityStatusMessage = 2;
    G_Action1Request action1Request = 3;
}

message G_Action2Response {
    google.protobuf.Timestamp DateTimeStamp = 1;
    string fileModifierStatusMessage = 2;
    G_Action2Request action2Request = 3;
}


message G_WindowsRequest {
    int32 requestId = 1;
    oneof RequestType{
        G_Action1Request action1Request = 2;
        G_Action2Request action2Requestion = 3;
    }
}

message G_WindowsRequestResponse {
    bool wasSuccessful = 1;
    string response = 2;
    oneof ResponseType{
        G_Action1Response action1Response = 3;
        G_Action2Response action2Respone = 4;
    }
}
```

**orchestrator.proto**

```
syntax = "proto3";
option csharp_namespace = "OrchestratorService";
package test;

import "service.proto";
import "windowsservice.proto";

service Orchestrator
{
  rpc RegisterClient(G_RegisterClientRequest) returns (stream G_Response) { }
  rpc EnqueueRequest(G_OrchestrationRequest) returns (G_Response) { }
}

message G_OrchestrationRequest{
  string originId = 1;
  oneof RequestType{
    G_RequestType1 requestType1 = 2;
    G_RequestType2 requestType2 = 3;
    G_Response response = 4;
    G_WindowsRequest windowsRequest = 5;
    G_WindowsRequestResponse windowsRequestResponse = 6;
  }
}

message G_RegisterClientRequest{
  string clientId = 1;
}

message G_Response{
  bool wasSuccessful = 1;
  string response = 2;
}
```

Here is the  definition from the csproj file for my Orchestrator project:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="../Protos/orchestrator.proto" GrpcServices="Server" ProtoRoot="../Protos/">
        <Link>Protos/orchestrator.proto</Link>
    </Protobuf>
    <Protobuf Include="../Protos/service.proto" GrpcServices="Client" ProtoRoot="../Protos/">
        <Link>Protos/service.proto</Link>
    </Protobuf>
    <Protobuf Include="../Protos/windowsservice.proto" GrpcServices="Client" ProtoRoot="../Protos/">
      <Link>Protos/windowservice.proto</Link>
    </Protobuf>
</ItemGroup>
```

Both **G_WindowsRequest** and **G_WindowsRequestResponse** are throwing a compiler error saying they are undefined. Is this an issue with **csharp_namespace** and/or **package** resolution?

Is there a way to enforce separate package/csharp_namespace definitions within the separate proto definitions, but reference those definitions within the rolled up "orchestrator" proto file definition?

**Here is a snippet of the compiler errors I am seeing:**

> 2>  orchestrator.proto(22,5): error : "G_WindowsRequest" is not
> defined. 2>  orchestrator.proto(23,5): error :
> "G_WindowsRequestResponse" is not defined. 2>Done building target
> "_Protobuf_CoreCompile" in project "Protos.csproj" -- FAILED. 2>
> 2>Done building project "Protos.csproj" -- FAILED. 2> 2>Build FAILED.
> 2> 2>orchestrator.proto(22,5): error : "G_WindowsRequest" is not
> defined. 2>orchestrator.proto(23,5): error :
> "G_WindowsRequestResponse" is not defined. 2>    0 Warning(s) 2>    2
> Error(s)

Comment: Can you add the full compiler message?

Comment: @EmondErno - Do you want me to append the compiler output to the Issue description? It's quite long.

Comment: Just the lines with the error